# Parsing huge logs efficiently having sections

Tags: scala, parsing, parallel-processing, machine-learning, bigdata

I have **huge log file**(in gigs) which has a heading (marking the beginning of information) and then the information follows.This is spread across the whole file randomly(meaning a heading followed by the info can occur anywhere in the log file). Also it has a parent child hierarchy as well. I need to parse and process the information of this log based on the regexes written to identify the beginning pattern of a section/heading and hence process the information which will follow.The problem here is I have to match all the regexes written for all the sections for each and every line of log file to determine which section is getting triggered . **This approach is very slow and also running into issues because of not having the intelligent idea of whats coming next from the log and it amplifies when there is a hierarchy**.I have thought of an approach of **indexing the file** by dividing file into chunks recursively (divide and conquer) and assigning it to multiple **actors(scala)** and each line could be matched against all the regexes in parallel(representing the beginning of sections).I want to know how efficient is the approach and **would like more inputs to improve the performance**.For the reference here is the pattern in which the log file may appear ::

```
Section1
--------------
Info for section1
..
...
....
.
.
Section2
--------------
Info for section2
..
...
....
.
.
Section3
=================
Info for section3

Child1 of section3
--------------
Info for child of section3

Child2 of section3
----------------
Info for child of section3

Child1 of child2 which is child of section3
.........................
Info for child1 of child2 which is child of section3

Section1
--------------       //Section1 reappears
Info for section1
..
...
....
.
.
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your file format. I would suggest storing this as structured data in an RDBMS or MongoDB as being the easiest solution, but if you want to use your own log format, you need to structure it so you know the start and end of each chunk, and the section/child number is structured so you don't need to use a regex.

Here is one possible solution. Each separate chunk is a JSON object, and is stored on its own line. So lines from your file could look like:

```
{"section": "1", "path": "/", "info": "Info for section1\nNext Line of info\nAnd so on..."}
{"section": "3", "path": "/child2/child1", "info": "Info for child1 of child2 which is child of section3"}
```

Comment: The constrain is that its a raw log and can't restructure it . Also if the file is huge then reading and re-structuring it and then reading it again to **process/mine** data out of it would make it real slow.

Comment: The only other idea I have is to try to generalize all your regexes into one, something like `Section(\d+)`. What marks the end of a chunk in your current system? Just the start of a new one?

Comment: It could be start of a new one or the end regex could be defined as well , but end regex is optional and this should be preserved.